# How to avoid calling `useCallback` conditionally when value isn't always a function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, algolia

`useRefinmentList` is an [Algolia hook](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/widgets/refinement-list/react/#hook-params-sortby) which accepts a `sortBy` prop.

The definition of `sortBy` is `type: string[] | (a: FacetValue, b: FacetValue) => number`.

If I pass in a sort function I wrap it in a `useCallback`, otherwise I pass in an array. This violates the rule that [hooks can’t be called conditionally](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html). In this case, useCallback is only called if `sortBy` is a sort function.

My code right now:

```js
useRefinementList({
  attribute: 'my_attribute',
  sortBy: sortBy?.length
    ? sortBy
    : useCallback(
        (a, b) => myCustomSortFunction(a, b, attribute),
        [attribute]
      ),
})
```

How can I refactor my code to conform to the rule?

Comment: Move useCallback out of useRefinementList? Then use _the resulting callback_ conditionally.

Comment: What is `myCustomSortFunction` and how is `attribute` related to `sortBy`?

Comment: @Bergi That code is just for illustration. In the app the sort function uses internal data (like sales/popularity) to sort the values. The sort could be different for each filter (attribute) X category page.

Comment: I was wondering whether that internal data is dynamic (depends on component state) and needs to be passed into the `myCustomSortFunction`, or whether it is static. In the latter case, you could declare all the compare functions outside of the component and only choose one of them dynamically inside the component. Then you wouldn't need a memoisation hook at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `useMemo` instead of `useCallback`:

```
useRefinementList(useMemo(
  () => ({
    attribute: 'my_attribute',
    sortBy: sortBy?.length
      ? sortBy
      : (a, b) => myCustomSortFunction(a, b, attribute),
  }),
  [sortBy, attribute]
))
```

or

```
useRefinementList({
  attribute: 'my_attribute',
  sortBy: useMemo(
    () => sortBy?.length
      ? sortBy
      : (a, b) => myCustomSortFunction(a, b, attribute),
    [sortBy, attribute]
  ),
})
```

Comment: I like the second solution, it's the cleanest so far.

Answer (score 1):

Does taking the hook out of the condition work for you?

```
const cb = useCallback(
  (a, b) => myCustomSortFunction(a, b, attribute),
  [attribute]
);

useRefinementList({
  attribute: "my_attribute",
  sortBy: sortBy?.length ? sortBy : cb,
});
```

Comment: Yep, that works, thanks. Although the DX of it is terrible...

Comment: yea ... hooks never been my favorite when it comes to DX